# NO_PUBKEY B53DC80D13EDEF05

Tags: apt, updates, sudo, gnupg, keyserver

When i run `sudo apt update` i get this error

```
Err:13 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY B53DC80D13EDEF05
Err:1 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt kubernetes-xenial InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY B53DC80D13EDEF05
```

and when i run `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys B53DC80D13EDEF05`

I got this

```
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).<br />
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.agtT5nydZc/gpg.1.sh --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys B53DC80D13EDEF05<br />
gpg: key B53DC80D13EDEF05: 1 duplicate signature removed<br />
gpg: key B53DC80D13EDEF05: "Rapture Automatic Signing Key (cloud-rapture-signing-key-2022-03-07-08_01_01.pub)" not changed<br />
gpg: Total number processed: 1<br />
gpg:              unchanged: 1<br />
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Not only is `apt-key` deprecated and you should be downloading and converting the key, your question is very unclear as to what you are trying to install or following.  All we can do is guess.  I know that the key for what you are doing is located at https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc and would need to be converted by running something similar to `curl -fsSL https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/apt-key.gpg`.  I would recommend to [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1483008/edit) your question and add more details.